# How to insert data into DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking online at different people's explanations of how to 
insert data using asp.net and C#, but so far all of the different things I have tried do nothing, why is my button not doing anything when I click to insert the data into my DB? also what do I use to differentiate between a textbox and a dropdown list, would I use the ddl.selecteditem that I am currently using and is that the best way? the majority of the source code online and tutorials that I have viewed deal with gridviews and I just have not been able to effectively translate that to what I need.

here is my HTML

```
           </td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Project Tester
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTester" runat="server"
                    DataTextField="" Width="203px" DataBound="ddlTester_DataBound"
                   AutoPostBack="False">
               </asp:DropDownList>
               &nbsp;
               <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString %>' 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [TesterName] FROM [Users] ORDER BY [TesterName]">
               </asp:SqlDataSource>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;
           </td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Project Name&nbsp;
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectName" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
               &nbsp;
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td style="height: 51px">
               &nbsp;
           </td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Project Description</td>
           <td style="height: 51px">
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="105px" Width="237px"></asp:TextBox>
               &nbsp;
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Assigned Date</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Due Date</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Project Platform</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProjectPlatform" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               BIOS</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBios" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               PCH</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPch" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               PROC</td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProc" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 51px; width: 377px; font-weight: bold;">
               Forward To</td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="employeeEmailDropDownList" runat="server" 
            Visible="True" 
                   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="EmailAddress" DataValueField="EmailAddress" Width="203px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString %>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [EmailAddress] FROM [Users] ORDER BY [TesterName]"></asp:SqlDataSource></td>    
       </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td style="width: 377px">
               &nbsp;</td>
           <td>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="CreateProject_Click"  
                   Text="Create Project" Font-Bold="true" Height="45px" Width="198px" />
               <asp:Label ID="errorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label ID="successLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td style="height: 29px">
               </td>
           <td style="height: 29px; width: 377px;">
               </td>
           <td style="height: 29px">
               </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
    </asp:Panel>

</asp:Content>
```

and here is the C# I have

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project_Set
{

    public partial class Projects_AddProject : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Populate1();
            }
        }

        protected void ddlTester_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Inserting an item in the 0 index of the DDL named "-Select-"
            //which will navigate the user to select an item
            ddlTester.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-"));
        }

        public void Populate1()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string connetionString = "Data Source=JVANCEX-MOBL2;Initial Catalog=ProjectsAndTasksTest; Trusted_Connection=True;";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TesterName AS FullName FROM [Users]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString));

                using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
                {

                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    SqlDataReader ddlValues;
                    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    ddlTester.DataSource = ddlValues;
                    ddlTester.DataValueField = "FullName";
                    ddlTester.DataTextField = "FullName";
                    ddlTester.DataBind();

                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    //cmd.Connection.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }

        public void CreateProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string connetionString = "Data Source=JVANCEX-MOBL2;Initial Catalog=ProjectsAndTasksTest; Trusted_Connection=True;";
                string insStmt = "INSERT INTO Projects (TesterName, ProjectName, ProjectDescription, DueDate, DateAssigned, Platform) values (@TesterName, @ProjectName,@ProjectDesc, @DueDate, @DateAssigned, @Platform)";

                using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    SqlCommand insCmd = new SqlCommand(insStmt, cnn);
                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", txtProjectName);
                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDesc", txtProjectDesc);

                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesterName", ddlTester.SelectedItem);

                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAssigned", txtStartDate);
                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", txtEndDate);
                    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", TxtProjectPlatform);
                    //insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bios", TxtBios.Text);
                    //insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pch", TxtPch.Text);
                    //insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Proc", TxtProc.Text);
                    insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cnn.Close();
                    //MessageBox.Show(affectedRows + " Project Created!");

                }

            }

        }
```

I know I need to be using .Parameters to protect against possible MySQL injection, but beyond that I am new to asp.net and C#.

Comment: for your first query you can do that a lot quicker using a `DataTable` and an inline query or storedproc as well

Comment: I would also suggest that you step thru the code. do you have any button click events or any other controls that would generate `autopostback` your logic looks a bit suspcious also `wrap your .ExecuteNonQuert` code around a `try{}catch(DbException ex){}` to trap / report on any errors that might happen.. do not assume that either of the query's will always execute successfully..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `if (!IsPostBack)` around your code that would otherwise insert data into the database, but the only way that event could be reached (apart from directly calling it from C#) would be if you clicked the button and caused a postback.

You need to remove that if statement from that method, and it should work.

You would have quickly noticed this if you had [set a breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) in your code and then stepped through. If you ever have a question about program flow, set a breakpoint and step through your code line by line.

Some other notes:

- You should move your connection string into a configuration file such as `web.config`. If you ever need to update it, that keeps you from having to rebuild the website. You can access it programmatically via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection string name here"].ConnectionString`
- I would move the code that creates the `SqlCommand` and sets the parameters. outside the using block, then do `insCmd.Connection = cnn;`. I like to keep my connection open for as little time as possible. This will also allow you to use the constructor that takes the command string as a parameter, so there will be no need for the `insStmt` variable.
- There is no `MessageBox` class for Web Forms like there is for WPF or WCF. Instead, you can have it execute some JavaScript when the page finishes loading on the client. For now, a simple `alert()` will do, but eventually you might spruce it up with something like [noty](http://ned.im/noty/#/about).
- You can use the implicitly typed variable `var` instead of setting the type explicitly for your variables. This makes the code shorter and easier to read, and easier to refactor if you end up changing types later. And it doesn't really have any disadvantages.
- You should wrap a try/catch around your insert command execution to catch any problems, and probably log an error somewhere, then show a generic "Sorry, an unexpected error occurred" to the client.
- The variables you are passing into your parameters are of type TextBox for the most part. That means you need to access the `.Text` property of them in order to get the entered text.
- If DateAssigned and DueDate are date types in your database, then you need to use `DateTime.TryParse` to make sure they're valid strings that represent a date. If they're not of the correct format, display an error message to the client and don't execute the insert command. The client should use some JavaScript to force the entered date into the right format (but don't rely on it, in case the user has JavaScript disabled).

To summarize all that, here's how I would write that event handler:

```
protected void CreateProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var insCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Projects (TesterName, ProjectName, ProjectDescription, DueDate, DateAssigned, Platform) values (@TesterName, @ProjectName,@ProjectDesc, @DueDate, @DateAssigned, @Platform)");
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", txtProjectName.Text);
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDesc", txtProjectDesc.Text);
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesterName", ddlTester.SelectedItem); //This should probably be .SelectedValue instead
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAssigned", txtStartDate.Text);
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", txtEndDate.Text);
    insCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", TxtProjectPlatform.Text);

    using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString))
    {
        insCmd.Connection = cnn;
        cnn.Open();            
        insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }

   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "insert-success", "alert('Project created');", true);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for your help that helped a lot, I have my connection string in the web.config file, for some reason I thought I needed to write it this way. I have used the configurationmanager statement before so I should have know I could use that as well. I had a try/catch setup on it when I was originally trying to get it all working, but I could not get it so I deleted it (should not have done that), I also had the .text on all of my textboxes but since it was not working I took them off to see if that worked, I just had not put them back on yet...

Comment: anything with a date in the DB is the date type, so I will use the datetime.tryparse, also than you for the link to noty I will definitely implement that